# Animate text position simultaneously with text changing in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to animate the position of `Expand` button, but instead it appears right at the final position. There's a strange hack `.transition(.scale)` that fixes my problem, but I hope to see a better not hacky solution.

```
struct TextView: View {

    @State var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("This is the most recent test comment with a picture. Lörem ipsum berölogi kjolprotest. Trist gigade. Sms-livräddare grönt elcertifikat.")
                .lineLimit(isExpanded ? nil : 2)

            HStack {
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        isExpanded.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(isExpanded ? "Less" : "Expand")
                }
                // .transition(.scale)
            }
        }
        .padding(.all)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .cornerRadius(13)
        .padding(.horizontal)

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `ZStack` containing Buttons in both states, and use the `.opacity` modifier to hide or show them…

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("This is the most recent test comment with a picture. Lörem ipsum berölogi kjolprotest. Trist gigade. Sms-livräddare grönt elcertifikat.")
                .lineLimit(isExpanded ? nil : 2)

            HStack {
                ZStack {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                isExpanded.toggle()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Less")
                        }
                        .opacity(isExpanded ? 1 : 0)
                    
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                isExpanded.toggle()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Expand")
                        }
                        .opacity(isExpanded ? 0 : 1)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.all)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .cornerRadius(13)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

[image]

Or alternatively, use `.matchedGeometryEffect`

```
if isExpanded {
    Button {
        withAnimation {
            isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    } label: {
        Spacer()
        Text("Less")
    }
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "button", in: namespace)
} else {
    Button {
        withAnimation {
            isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    } label: {
        Spacer()
        Text("Expand")
    }
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "button", in: namespace)
}
```

Obviously there's some duplication so you would pull the `Button` out into a `func` or its own `View` `struct`.